# Why I cannot access project properties in "plugins" section of build.gradle.kts with Gradle Kotlin DSL (5.0)?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Gradle 5.0, Kotlin DSL

Create `gradle.properties` file:

```
kotlinVersion=1.3.10
```

Create `build.gradle.kts` file:

```
val kotlinVersion: String by project

println(kotlinVersion) // works

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm").version(kotlinVersion)
    //                    ^ Unresolved reference: kotlinVersion

}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

tasks.register("compute") {
    doLast {
        println(kotlinVersion) // works
    }
}
```

Run `gradle compute`, then change

```
kotlin("jvm").version(kotlinVersion)
```

to

```
kotlin("jvm").version("1.3.10")
```

and run again. Everything works.

Am I just doing something wrong? Or is it some sort of limitation or a bug?

I just wanted to move the Kotlin version out of the build script, so I could play with changing it later (e.g. via command line, `... -PkotlinVersion=1.3.0`) and also to keep it the same both for dependencies and plugins.

Answer (score 2):

I typically use the `buildSrc` directory to define objects that represent versions or properties that I wish to reuse, especially when I have multiple projects or multiple dependencies that stay lock-step with versioning. I put together a little example project [here](https://github.com/tehbilly/gradle-kotlin-dsl-plugin-versioning) that demonstrates usage.

In `buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/Versions.kt` I have:

```kotlin
object Versions {
    // Library versions
    val Kotlin = "1.3.10"
    val logback = "1.2.3"

    // Plugin versions
    object Plugins {
        // Can be changed if we want to use a version other than one matching the library version
        val Kotlin = Versions.Kotlin
    }
}
```

And I use it elsewhere like so:

```kotlin
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version Versions.Plugins.Kotlin
}

// snip...

dependencies {
    compile(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
    compile(group = "ch.qos.logback", name = "logback-classic", version = Versions.logback)
}
```

These are statically defined in the `Versions.kt` file, but you could also read them from the environment, or a file, or properties. The real key is that your `buildSrc` is evaluated *before* everything else, so it's available for all of the other phases in your build script *(At least all the ones I've tried!)*.

Comment: A bonus is that you can include that compiled class into application so this info is available at runtime.

Comment: Hadn't even thought of that! Could be a little more ergonomic than a gradle task to create a file of all dependencies and versions (for instance).

Answer (score 1):

The `plugins` block is evaluated separately from the rest of the build script, because the set of plugins you're using determines the classpath (and the name resolution scope) for the rest of the build script. Because of that, declarations outside of the `plugins` block cannot be used inside that block.

Comment: Is there any way to externalize that version?

Answer (score 1):

As @yole said in his answer, the `plugins { ... }` block is a special construct that is evaluated before the rest of the build script and has limited access to the Gradle model.

One way to pass a property and use it in the `plugins { ... }` DSL is to use [system properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html):

```
val kotlinVersion = System.getProperty("kotlinVersion")?.toString() 
    ?: error("Add a 'kotlinVersion' system property or pass -DkotlinVersion=...")
id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform").version(kotlinVersion)
```

The way to pass a system property via command line is `-DkotlinVersion=1.3.0`.

Comment: is this not possible to use `-P` instead of `-D` arguments?

Comment: @mochadwi, with the recent Gradle versions, you can manage plugin versions using `pluginManagement` in `settings.gradle.kts`, and you can use project properties there, see: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugin_version_management

Answer (score 0):

Properties can be accessed by:

```
project.properties["kotlinVersion"]
```